# Responsive elements in css/html - not Flash

Tags: html, css

I need to create something like a responsive city(simcity) in html/css.

I do have a design and every building have to be click-able.

So every building has to be a separate element on the one background.

How can I place all them elements to be responsive in the way that they will getting smaller on small screen and their position will be correct.

Should I use position absolute on them elements and percentage.

Please give any advice.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Use absolute positioning on those elements and then position those elements with the top and left properties.

If you want the top, left, width, and height properties proportional to the width of the screen you should use percentages on all of those elements.